# RestKit 0.10 Installation code fails to find Core Data related extensions

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit, xcode4.3

I've replaced the RestKit 0.9 with 0.10. Went through all the installation steps. Now I'm getting selectors not found errors.

It appears that these selectors are related to core data header being imported instead of the rest kit based core data

```
No visible @interface for 'RKManagedObjectStore' declares the selector 'save'
No known class method for selector 'managedObjectContext'
No visible @interface for 'RKClient' declares the selector 'get:queryParams:delegate:'
```

This is driving me nuts over the past 2 hours. Please help!

[RestKitInstallation instructions](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x)

[image: error description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Xcode project settings related bug. I had to remove all rest kit imports, close the project, re-import restkit. A lot of stabbing in the dark, but it finally went away

Answer (score 0):

is it because you havnt configured restkit to be used with ARC on ios5?